# can zuul be retryable without eureka and without ribbon?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am a beginner in zuul.
now I try to use zuul as a reverse proxy for my mircoservices.because I am not using ribbon or eureka,so I do:

```
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

I also notice that I can set:

```
zuul.retryable=true
```

to make zuul retryable.
But it seems not work in my project, so I want to know whether zuul retry should be used with ribbon? Or there is any other solution in this situation?

Comment: No it can not be retryable without ribbon

Comment: @spencergibb so, if I set " ribbon.eureka.enabled=false "means I am not using ribbon? or I still can use ribbon?